# Redirection out using open

Tags: c, io

Im making a shell and working on output redirection, specifically appending to files. Problem is, the following code always overwrites the contents of the file and does not simply append.

```
int val = -1;
//Flag issue?
val = open(destination, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

if (val != -1) {
    close(1);
    dup(val);
    close(val);
}
```

Comment: Not a fix, but maybe `dup2` would be better.

Comment: This code works for me as it's intended to. You're probably overwritting the file somewhere else. You need to give us more code/details!

Comment: Note that using `dup2()` is often considered better than using `dup()`.  Just check that `val` is not the same as the target file descriptor (`1` in this case, aka `STDIN_FILENO`).